# Change key in unordered multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

Is there some efficient way to change key in unordered multimap? For example, I want to change key from `key_val1` to `key_val2`. It looks like this can be done much efficiently than iterating over `equal_range(...)` and readding all pairs for the new key with subsequent erasing the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>No. If you want to change keys, you have little choice but to delete the existing item, create a new item with the new key, and insert the new item into the set.</strike>

An `unordered_multi(set|map)` is (at least normally) implemented as a hash table. Any change in the key requires computing the hash for the new key (which may be *entirely* different from the hash for the old key, even though the key is only slightly modified).

Thinking about things, you probably *can* actually do this if you're ambitious enough. I'm not at all sure it's worthwhile, but it is probably possible. In particular, the unordered associative containers support what are called `local iterators`. A local iterator can iterate through the items in a specific bucket in the table. By definition, all items with equal keys must be in the same bucket.

So, you'd start by getting a local iterator to the bucket containing your items. Then you'd iterate through that using `key_equal` to find all the items it contains that have the same key. Then you'd use the hasher to find the new bucket for all of those, and directly move them all to the new bucket.

I've never actually done this, so I'm not *certain* the local_iterator gives you enough access to do it--but it does seem like it at least *might* be possible--likely enough to be worth further investigation, anyway.

My own take on things is that if you're likely to do this often enough to bother optimizing the task, it would probably be worth considering using an `unordered_map<key, std::vector<whatever>>`, so you'd only have one stored key, with an arbitrary number of items associated with it. Then if you need to modify that key, moving all the associated data with it is trivial (happens pretty much automatically).

Comment: Very sad.... Because it looks like hash computation for the new key can be done 1 time instead of multiple times. Also moving all values for the old key to the new bucket in one operation will be computationally cheaper then moving them all one by one and erasing old ones.

Comment: @gkuzmin: why don't use a `unordered_map<Key, std::vector<Value>>` then ? This way you'll move the `Key` only once.

Comment: @gkuzmin: After some thought, I've changed my answer--but ultimately, I agree with MatthieuM: if you're doing this often enough to care, one key with a vector (or deque, etc.) of associated items probably makes sense.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Answer is interesting and comment about using some other container as map value is interesting too. I think that second choice is appropriate for my case, but I decided to try graph based approach for my task and currently I have linear algorithm. So no heavy data structure needed now. Approach with container as value will be slightly worse because of potential a lot of moves (in my particular task). So I will stay with graph. Thanks for your reply anyway!